# Is This A Image Of A linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let there be $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$

$T(0,-1,1)=(3,3,3)$

$T(1,0,-1)=(0,1,1)$

$T(1,1,0)=(1,2,-1)$

Is (1,2,3) is the only image of the vector $(1, \frac{-7}{9}, \frac{-8}{9})$?

I have thought to create a matrix $[T]^T_E$*$[T]^E_C$=$[T]^T_C$
so I will have a matrix that does the transformation and the I can check the calim, but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it follows easily from the fact that $T$ has rank 3, so $T$ is invertible. In particular, it is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have since $T$ is linear that $T(c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2} + c_{3}v_{3}) = c_{1}T(v_{1}) + c_{2}T(v_{2}) +  c_{3}T(v_{3})  $.

Notice that $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  So, that means:

$T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \right ) = T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 2\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \right ) = \dfrac{1}{2}T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \right ) = \dfrac{1}{2}T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right ) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left ( T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right ) + T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \right )  + T \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right ) \right ) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}   \right )  = \dfrac{1}{2} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}  \right )  = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ \frac{3}{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

So, the first column of the corresponding matrix $A$ for $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ \frac{3}{2} \end{bmatrix}$.  Can you figure out the other columns?  Once you do, $A \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ will give you the image of the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ under $T$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $(1,2,3)$ as linear combination of $(0,-1,1),(1,0,-1),(1,1,0)$, it will be:

$$(1,2,3)=3(1,1,0)-2(1,0,-1)+(0,-1,1)$$

Next use fact, that $T$ is linear, so image of $(1,2,3)$ is:

$$T(1,2,3)=T[3(1,1,0)-2(1,0,-1)+(0,-1,1)]=3T(0,-1,1)-2T(1,0,-1)+T(1,1,0)$$

Comment: the image is (1,2,3) but you put it in the domain, its need to be $T(1, \frac{-7}{9}, \frac{-8}{9})=(1,2,3)$